# Calling a service while route is defined/changed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to call a service modalService and function setLoginModal when route is either **/registration** or **/login**.

So when route is changed I need get start.html view and modal which is being called by modalService.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var myApp = window.angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

    myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/home', { templateUrl: 'views/start.html' });
        $routeProvider.when('/registration', { templateUrl: 'views/start.html'});
        $routeProvider.when('/login', { templateUrl: 'views/start.html' });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
    }]);
})();
```

Service is:

```
(function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.factory('modalService', ['$modal',
    function ($modal) {

        function setLoginModal() {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'partials/loginModal.html',
                controller: 'loginController',
                size: 'sm',
                backdrop: 'static'
            });
        };

        return {
            setLoginModal: setLoginModal
        };
    }]);
})(angular.module('myApp'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
$routeProvider.when('/registration', { templateUrl: 'views/start.html', controller: 'authController' });
$routeProvider.when('/login', { templateUrl: 'views/start.html', controller: 'authController' });
...
```

and

```
myApp.controller('authController', function (modalService) {
    modalService.setLoginModal();
});
```

You can also create `modalSummon` directive that does the same thing and include it in view templates of your choice. Just be aware of multiple modal invocations and sporadic template recompilations.

Comment: ha, we pretty much said exactly the same thing

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of different ways you could call this service when those routes are called.

The simplest would probably be to inject it into a controller that is loaded in those views and call it from there, either from within the route controller or with the ng-controller directive in /registration and /login views like `<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl"></div>` like:

```
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function (modalService) {
  modalService.setLoginModal();
});
```

Another way to do it, (which would probably only make sense if you were building logic onto specific "from" and "to" route path) would be to put a watch statement in a global controller and call it if the path change matches your flow:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
 ... you could trigger something here ...
});
```

Both of those methods might have their place, but I think you might better be able to rethink your question and instead build an "authLauncher" directive that accomplishes everything you're trying to do, moving your factory logic into said directive instead.